# Contract getFunds call which should send wrapped ERC20 token to owner reverts, why?

Tags: erc-20, transfer, modifiers

My smart contract holds a few WETH. I have this function in my contract:

```js
    function getFunds(address tokenAddress) external onlyOwner{
        IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
        uint balance = token.balanceOf(address(this)); 
        uint balanceOwner = token.balanceOf(owner);

        assert(token.transfer(owner, balance));

        assert(token.balanceOf(owner) == balanceOwner + balance);
    }
```

I call getFunds with the correct WETH address and from the correct owner address.

But still, the tx reverts with 20% gas used,  and I don't know why. What can be the reason?

I tested everything via hardhat and there it works.

EDIT: This is the way I call the contract in production via web3js:

```js
        let myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(myContractAbi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS)
    
        const tx = myContract.methods.getFunds(WETH) //WETH constant with correct address 
        const data = tx.encodeABI()
      
        let currentGasPriceInWei = parseInt(await web3.eth.getGasPrice())
      
        const txData = {
          from: OWNER_ADDRESS,
          to: CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
          data: data,
          gasPrice: web3.utils.toBN(currentGasPriceInWei),
          gas: 35000  
        }         
        
        web3.eth.sendTransaction(txData)
        ...
```

Comment: Can you share a tx hash of the failing transaction. Also the address of WETH (there are multiple, but I would assume you use [WETH9](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#code) and what network ;)

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote WETH to simplify things, but actually its WFTM on the Fantom network.  WFTM adrress is correct, I prefer to keep the tx private, but I can share tx details of course :)

Comment: So this one https://ftmscan.com/address/0x21be370d5312f44cb42ce377bc9b8a0cef1a4c83#code ?

Comment: Exactly, yes that is the address :)

Comment: Are you sure about the `gas` parameter? Looking at fmtscan I can see wfmt transfers that take quite some more gas, so I would probably try setting this to 100k just to test it.

Comment: I also tried it with 200000 gas, same result.

Comment: Hmmm sorry, I cannot spot the error :(

Comment: since you have the hash you could try to debug the transaction with tenderly.dev ~or take a look at the traces on fmtscan~, to see what it internally reverts on. This is normally quite helpful ;) Edit: no traces for fmtscan :( so only tenderly